# Module not found error with rospkg when trying to import roslib

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roslib, rospkg, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have developed a custom control algorithm for mz robot in gazebo. Untile yesterday I used to use

```
roslaunch spider_gazebo spider_world.launch
```

to spawn the robot and load control configurations in gazebo and then in another terminal i used to export ROS_MASTER_URI and then use

```
rosrun spider_control control.py
```

to run my custom python plugin. Until yesterday this was working well, but today when I tried to launch again `I am  having the following error

```
    'Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/microbot/catkin_ws/src/spider/spider_control/control.py", line 5, in <module>
     import roslib
   File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
     from roslib.launcher import load_manifest
    File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 42, in <module>
      import rospkg
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rospkg'
```

I have also tried the following command to check whether my python path is right or not ,

```
 'echo $PYTHONPATH'
```

The output is

```
  '/home/microbot/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist- 
    packages:/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros/core/roslib/src
```

I can not understand whats causing this error. can any one please help me point out the reason. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328742/module-not-found-error-with-rospkg-when-trying-to-import-roslib/) by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2019-07-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe I have found the answer. The python-rospkg i have instaled are from python 2.7 version. Every time I install them, they get installed directly in /usr/lib/python2.7/distro-package  path. But my terminal is sourcing only my work space and ros path. Also the plugin I am trying to run is built with python3. Since the python-rospkg I have installed are for python2.7, I am having this error

The second error with tensorflow is because , I have installed tensorflow for python3 and when I manually set the python path to python2.7/distro-package, it can not find tensor flow and hence this enum error.

PS: careful when trying to install python3-rospkg, when performing binary instalation, it is automatically removing plenty of ros related python2.7 packages. Unfortunately major commands in ros like roslaunch, rosrun etc still use python2.7

---

Originally posted by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) with karma: 96 on 2019-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2019-07-26**:
https://answers.ros.org/question/237613/how-to-define-ros-kinetic-to-use-python3-instead-of-python27/ might be the best thread regarding Python 2 & 3 issues for ROS1, fyi.

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on 2019-07-28**:
thank you for the heads up.

**Comment by [polykb](https://answers.ros.org/users/73596/polykb/) on 2021-04-22**:
@microbot were you able to fix the issue?  I'm facing the exact same problem.
I would be thankful if you could guide me.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-04-22**:
@polykb  Please open a new thread, and refer to this thread. Person who posted a question or answered won't necessarilly come back to this thread so chance for you to get responses is slim if you ask a question in the comment section. Also condition of each question can be more or less different.